# Proxy settings config. 407 proxy error

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

I have problem when I try apt-get update i get error:

> 407  Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires
>   authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter
>   is denied.  )

How ever I can use internet from Mozilla, when I set proxy parameters. Any ideas how to fix this?

> /etc/apt/apt.conf file all good.

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu, legacy from other developer. Any ideas how to check that or fix it?

Comment: type the command `echo $http_proxy` and tell its output

Answer (score 1):

Does your proxy require authentication? If yes, then your apt.conf file should look like this

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@server:port";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@server:port";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:password@server:port";
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks://username:password@server:port";
```

**Note :**
Mozilla Firefox works fine because it accesses the proxy from network setting and asks authentication when you open firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu desktops in a corporate environment.  My Firefox and apt.conf proxies are the same.  My 'procedure' is to open Firefox which then prompts me for my user ID and password to authenticate the proxy when I navigate to an external website.  I can then apt-get update etc. with no errors.  If I don't authenticate using Firefox first, I get 407 errors.

Comment: I tried, but its not working. '407  Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
'